# "您好,我是否能知道原因呢" translate to "Hello, can I know the reason"

Tags: translation

I translate "您好,我是否能知道原因呢" to "Hello, can I know the reason"
But it looks like lose courtesy meaning.

How to normally behavior courtesy meaning this chinese sentence in english?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word 您 as an alternate for 你, implicates that you really respect the person you are talking, thus, you would also need to use 'May I' to show politeness while asking.

I would translate it as follow:

Greetings Sir/Madam, may I know what is the reason?